# If $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$ converges does $\lim(a_{2n}) = \lim(a_{3n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$ converges does $\lim(a_{2n}) = \lim(a_{3n})$?

I tried ${\sim}\infty$ possibilities but couldnt find a counter example so I tend to believe it is true?

Comment: Consider $(a_{6n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The series $a_{6n}$ is a subsequence of $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$.  It therefore converges to some limit $L$.  Then if $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$ converge, they must converge to $L$

Answer (score 1):

if $(a_{2n})$ converges to $l$ then its subsequence $(a_{6n})$ converges to the same limit $l$. if $(a_{3n})$ converges to $m$ then its subsequence $(a_{6n})$ converges to the same limit $m$. Uniqeness of the limit of a convergent sequence guarantees $l=m$ so $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{3n})$ has the same limit.

Thanks for warning.