# Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ exists iff

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ exists iff

A. $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$  and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+2}$ exists

B.$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$ exists

C.$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n}$ , $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1}$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{3n}$ exists

D. None of Above

I need to think of sequence such that conditions are options are violated but limit exists to remove options. But i am not coming up with such

Thanks for help

Comment: Should options A., B., C. include wording to the effect that the limits mentioned exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For A and B, consider $a_n = (-1)^n$.

Then, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n} = 1$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+1} = -1$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{2n+2} = 1$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ doesn't exist.

For C, look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035250/does-a-n-converges-if-and-only-if-a-2n-a-3n-a-2n-1-converge).

Comment: So 
Answer is C ?

Comment: ^Yes, that is correct.